# Ignore an element inside <Link></Link> to not navigate on click

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to get to work a delete btn which is inside a div which is wrapped in react-router-dom  tag. I want to be able to navigate to the established path when that div is clicked. But if the target is that delete btn, then it shouldn't navigate just execute the onClick inside the delete btn. Is this possible? I couldn't figure out on my own. Thanks for reading.

```
<ul className="m-entries">    
  {
    letters.map(letter => {        
      return (
        <li className="o-entry" key={ letter.id }>
          <Link to={`/Letters/letter/${ letter.id }`}>
            <div className="l-entry-container">
              <div className="l-entry__header">
                <h2 className="c-text__h2 c-letter-title">{ letter.title }</h2>
                // This is the delete btn
                <button 
                  className="c-entry__btn c-entry__dlt-btn"
                  onClick={(e) => {                        
                    displayConfirmDeleteWdw(e, letter.id)
                  }}
                  type="button"
                >                    
                  <XDeleteBtn />                      
                </button>                                
              </div>              
              <p className="c-text__p c-letter__preview">{ letter.synopsis }</p>
            </div>                
          </Link>
        </li>           
    )})
  }                  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's generally considered bad UI/UX to place interactive DOM elements within other interactive DOM elements (*in fact some elements are sometimes illegal when used like this*), but there is a way to accomplish this.

The button's `onClick` event should not propagate up to the `Link` component. Call `stopPropagation` on the event to prevent it from bubbling up further.

```
<ul className="m-entries">
  {letters.map(letter => {
    return (
      <li className="o-entry" key={letter.id}>
        <Link to={`/Letters/letter/${letter.id}`}>
          <div className="l-entry-container">
            <div className="l-entry__header">
              <h2 className="c-text__h2 c-letter-title">{letter.title}</h2>
              <button
                className="c-entry__btn c-entry__dlt-btn"
                onClick={(e) => {
                  e.stopPropagation(); // <-- prevent event from bubbling up
                  displayConfirmDeleteWdw(e, letter.id);
                }}
                type="button"
              >
                <XDeleteBtn />      
              </button>
            </div>
            <p className="c-text__p c-letter__preview">{letter.synopsis}</p>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </li>
    )})
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: I see. I'd like to know what is a better way to accomplish this!. How would you put a delete btn for each <li> without having to do what I did? Thanks for the response.

Comment: @glowbo The `button` could be a sibling to `Link` if you didn't want to nest it. It sort of depends on your UI designs I suppose.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: @glowbo Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!